# officer seems to have a first slide by default

Tags: r, officer

When I build a pptx deck in officer, I notice that the Title slide seems added by default. I can assume the structure of the Title Slide is present and begin adding content. However, only for this slide I see a mishmash of placeholder text and content (see image below). The placeholder text does not appear in presentation mode, but it does cause confusion for viewers outside of presentation mode so I am wondering what i can do about this.

```
library(officer)

my_pres <- read_pptx(path = file_template) 

my_pres <- 
  ph_with(
    my_pres, 
    value = 'Programmatic Presentations', 
    location = ph_location_type(type = "ctrTitle") # note that this type argument was taken from the prior plot
  )

my_pres <- 
  ph_with(
    my_pres, 
    value = 'Joseph Powers', 
    location = ph_location_type(type = "subTitle") # note that this type argument was taken from the prior plot
  )
```

[image]

Comment: If your file already contains some content, it won't be deleted unless you delete it. I think `file_template` contains a slide that contains a title...

Comment: Thank you David, there was a blank slide present in the normal view of the template. Removing that slide resolved my issue.